# Is there a reason that csv.DictWriter will not input a value?

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping

I'm building a web scraper that retrieves a hashtag and two values associated with that hashtag. it then puts the information into a csv file.

The problem I'm having is that a cell will be created for the hashtag, but the tag itself will not be inputted.

```
with open('Test.csv', 'w', newline='')as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['Tags', 'value1', 'value2']
    info = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    info.writeheader()

    for i in range(1, 3):

        tags = soup.find_all('span', class_='tag')[i].get_text()
        tags = tags.replace('#', '')
        time.sleep(2)

        value1 = soup.find_all('span', class_="value1")[i].get_text()
        time.sleep(2)

        value2 = soup.find_all('span', class_="value2")[i].get_text()

        info.writerow({'Tags': tags, 'value1': value1, 'value2': value2})
        #there is a problem with tags. They are not created in the csv file, it's just a blank space
        print(tags, ' ', value1, ' ', value2)
```

Everything else works fine, even the print statement shows all the information.

Answer (score 0):

In this line :

```py
info.writerow({'Tags': tags, 'value1': value1, 'value2': value2})
```

The two variables `value1` and `value2` are not referenced. Maybe what you want is

```py
info.writerow({'Tags': tags, 'value1': viewers, 'value2': rooms})
```

That also explains why your print statement works well, since you use the `viewers` and `rooms` variables in it.

But I find it weird that you don't get any `NameError` error...

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't getting a name error because I edited the code to be posted. I just did not edit the code well.